# Swaption on a swap with 0 year tenor

Tags: option-pricing, interest-rates, swaps, swaption, irs

Any ideas on valuation of IRS swaption on a swap with 0 year tenor?

As an example, we have a 5 year swaption, on expiration it is cash settled; the underlying swap tenor is 0 years with excercise and maturity set on the same day.

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you write out the payoff in math terms?

Answer (score 1):

from a practitioner perspective, i can say there's no such thing as a 0 year swap (obviously).  The shortest tenor that you could trade would be a contract on one month LIBOR or more likely 3 month LIBOR.  Then the instrument you are asking about is a 5 year expiration caplet (payoff in 5 years = max (0, LIBOR- strike).)